# How to filter by "begins with"?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, sum

If I have the following data.frame that has 2 columns (`Code` and `Value`):

```
Code  Value
A111  5
B111  10
C111  15
A222  20
B222  25
C222  30
```

And I have the following groups:

> Group 1 = All codes that start with A
>
> Group 2 = All codes that start with B and C

I would like to calculate:

- The sum of `Value` for Group 1.
- The sum of `Value` for Group 2.
- A vector with the weights of each `Value` with respect to the total `Value` of the group it belongs to, i.e, for A111 it will be .2 (5 divided by the total Value for Group 1, which is 25).

Comment: Do all codes start with either A, B or C?

Answer (score 2):

Get the data:

```
test <- data.frame(Code = c("A111", "B111", "C111", "D111", "E111", "A222", "B222", "C222", "D222", "E222" ),
Value = c(5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 30L, 35L, 45L, 55L, 60L),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Make the grouping variable for the codes using the first letter (`fl`):

```
fl <- substr(test$Code,1,1)
groups <- ifelse(fl %in% c("A","B"), 1,
          ifelse(fl %in% c("C","D"), 2, 
          3))
```

Calculate a weight using `ave` to calculate the `sum` within each group.

```
test$Weight <- test$Value / ave(test$Value,groups,FUN=sum)
test

   Code Value    Weight
1  A111     5 0.0625000
2  B111    10 0.1250000
3  C111    15 0.1111111
4  D111    20 0.1481481
5  E111    25 0.2941176
6  A222    30 0.3750000
7  B222    35 0.4375000
8  C222    45 0.3333333
9  D222    55 0.4074074
10 E222    60 0.7058824
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!, this is exactly what I needed, but actually I need to replicate this for 7 Groups in my real example.

How would it be if I add a 3rd Group, Say, the following example:

test <- data.frame(Code = c("A111", "B111", "C111", "D111", "E111", "A222", "B222", 
"C222", "D222", "E222"  ), Value = c(5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 30L, 35L, 45L, 55L, 60L),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Group 1 = All codes that start with A
# Group 2 = All codes that start with B and C
# Group 3 = All codes that start with D and E

Comment: You will have to make a more detailed grouping variable using something like `ifelse` - I have updated the answer.